# Database system table problem

Tags: database

I read this article.
Where is the location of "system" table.

Is the image "system" table? 
[image]

[phpMyAdmin](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632)

To disable a module via phpMyAdmin you must login to phpMyAdmin. Then you must locate the database where Drupal is installed. Once you have done so look for the "system" table. Click and open it. Click to browse the table. Find the record for the module that is causing the problems and select the edit function. Set the status to "0" and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the `system` table, which stores details about available modules, themes and theme engines.

For more information about the system table schema, refer to the technical documentation at:

[`system_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_schema/7)

from:

```
 $schema['system'] = array(
    'description' => "A list of all modules, themes, and theme engines that are or have been installed in Drupal's file system.",
```

and also, it's usage by:

[`system_list`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/system_list/7)

> Builds a list of bootstrap modules and enabled modules and themes.

Answer (score 0):

To address problems in the system table (as in the title of your question), you may also try to use contributed module "[Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)". That module integrates with Drush via the `Drush RR` command. It will then rebuild the system table.

[DrupalEasy Podcast #133](http://drupaleasy.com/podcast/2014/06/drupaleasy-podcast-133-top-secret-drupal-capital-camp-gov-days) further explains how this module / drush cmd can be used.